# Determine Rank and Channel Bits in Haswell Physical Address Space

Tags: mapping, reverse-engineering, intel, cpu-architecture, chipset

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` (`Haswell`). The chipset datasheets include [Datasheet, volume 1 (M- and H-processor lines)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328901) and [Datasheet, volume 2 (M- and H-processor lines)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328902). The physical address mapping is as follows:
[image]
I want to know **which bits** of the physical address determine the **target** *rank* and *channel*. Based on *Volume 2*, if *high-order rank-interleaving* is enabled, either of the address bits **20-27** can be used:
[image]
Does this mean that if I used *high-order rank-interleaving*, I can **choose** the rank bit, and, otherwise, the rank bit should be detected **using** *reverse-engineering*? How about the *channel* bits?

---

P.S.: The chipset supports **two** *channels*, each supporting up to **two** *DIMMs*, each supporing up to **two** *ranks*.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in a bit of a hurry. Meanwhile, see [this](https://os.itec.kit.edu/downloads/publ_2017_hillenbrand_xeon_decoding.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! I will check that. But I have a *Laptop* `Haswell` processor. Will `Xeon` *physical memory address layout* match that?

Comment: mmm, probably not. The big difference is that your laptop is single-socket, so the whole SAD this is not used. You can use that PDF as a starting point but nothing more. The exact mapping is not public and must be reverse-engineered. It's not trivial :(